# How to convert a bread recipe to Tangzhong Method?

Tags: baking

I would like to know how can I covert my bread/pastry recipe  and apply the Tangzhong method.

Comment: There is no set way to convert, it depends on the type of bread and the recipe. Please edit with the recipe you want to convert and the result you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

King Arthur has a [description](https://www.kingarthurbaking.com/blog/2018/07/23/how-to-convert-a-bread-recipe-to-tangzhong):

> The typical sandwich bread or dinner roll recipe (like these Golden Pull-Apart Butter Buns) has a hydration level of around 60% to 65%.
>
> But when you’re using the tangzhong method, you want your recipe’s hydration to be about 75%.
>
> Why? Because when using tangzhong, some of the liquid in the dough is “trapped” by the pre-cooked slurry (the tangzhong), and thus plays no part in the dough’s texture; as far as hydration is concerned, it’s as if that liquid isn’t even there.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is how to convert a recipe.

Comment: I think in general it answers the question: the asker only has to increase the hydration to 75%, and proceed with the Tangzhong method.

Comment: I think you miss the point on this one @G.B. , adding the tangzhong is what increases the hydration. This will have other impacts which need to be considered.